# Mean value theorem question - proving F constant - answer check

Tags: calculus, constants, mean-value-theorem

The question:
Given $f$ continuity at $[a,b]$ and derivative at $(a,b)$.
It is known $f'(x)=0$ for each x belongs to $(a,b)$.
prove $f$ is constant.
My Answer:
Need to prove $f(x)=k$ for each X belongs to $[a,b]$
Creating a new function: $$g(x)=f(x)-k$$
$g(x)$ is also continuity and derivative at $[a,b]$ and thus I can use the Mean value theorem
I will get $$g(b)-g(a)=0$$
because it is known the derivative equals zero, If I do derivative on $g(x)$, I will get:
$$g'(x)=f'(x)$$ $$g'(x)=0$$ Thus $$g(b)=g(a)$$
Then I just use the value $a$ and $b$ and do: $$g(b)=f(b)-k$$ $$g(a)=f(a)-k$$ and get $$f(b)=f(a)$$ and that's it
Sorry for the bad english... my english is not that great, I hope it will be forgiven :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try starting here instead of defining an auxiliary function. Suppose $a\leq x\leq b$. By the mean value theorem there is a $c_x\in [a,x]$ such that $f'(c_x) = \frac{f(x)-f(a)}{x-a}$.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comment, actually the question I asked, the solution you gave , is the same solution they did :)
but I wanted to know if my answer is good, because I did not think of it at the beginning. only after I saw the video ( answer ), I realized how easy the question is.
But basically, is it good? my answer? even if it got a little complicated hehe

Comment: The method behind the proof is the same. You just introduced a few extra steps, by introducing an auxiliary function. However, you only so far proved $f(b)=f(a)$.

Comment: Yea, by proving $f(b)=f(a)$ I proved its constant. for every x inside the function, it is equals, i showed that between two different $x$'s, which are different and is parameter like, it is equal, so it doesnt matter which x I choose, its constant. every $f(x)$ is the same.

Comment: To the man who disliked this post, thank you very much, just so you know, you are helping people move away from this forum by doing this... you are making people not ask questions, they try hard to ask using latex and their english, although their english is bad and you still dislike... thank you very much ( didnt talk to you Doge chan, sorry it was on your message ).